# Socket connects to a port on a non existant ip address

Tags: c++, sockets

I have the following code used to socket connect to a server running on Ubuntu 15.10:

```
    void Connect(std::string address, int port)
    {
            struct addrinfo hints;
            struct addrinfo *result = NULL;
            struct addrinfo *rp = NULL;
            int sfd, s;

            std::cout << "Connecting to address " << address << " port " << port << std::endl;

            std::memset(&hints, 0, sizeof(struct addrinfo));

            hints.ai_family = AF_UNSPEC;        /* Allow IPV4 or IPV6 */
            hints.ai_socktype = SOCK_DGRAM;     /* Datagram socket */
            hints.ai_flags = 0;
            hints.ai_protocol = 0;              /* Any protocol */

            std::string portStr;
            portStr = std::to_string(port);

            s = getaddrinfo(address.c_str(), portStr.c_str(), &hints, &result);

std::cout << "ADDRESS-------------> " << s << std::endl;
            if (s != 0)
            {
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << "Cannot resolve hostname " << address << gai_strerror(s);
                throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
            }

            /*
             *  getaddrinfo() returns a list of address structures. We should try each
             *  address until we successfull bind. If socket() or connect() fails, we close the socket
             *  and try the next address until the end.
             */
            for (rp = result; rp != NULL; rp = rp->ai_next)
            {
    std::cout << "loop-----------------> " << rp->ai_family << std::endl;
                sfd = socket(rp->ai_family, rp->ai_socktype, rp->ai_protocol);
    std::cout << "sfd-----------------> " << sfd << std::endl;

                if (sfd == -1)
                    continue;

    /*
                 *  If connect succeed, the address was found.
                 */
                int sts = connect(sfd, rp->ai_addr, rp->ai_addrlen);

    std::cout << "sts-----------------> " << sts << std::endl;

                if (sts == 0)
                    break;

                close(sfd);
            }

            /*
             *  Check for failure
             */
            if (rp == NULL)
            {
                std::stringstream ss;
                ss << "Cannot find server address at " << address << " port " << port;
                throw std::runtime_error(ss.str());
            }

            freeaddrinfo(result); /* Object no longer needed */

    std::cout << "SOCKET-----------------> " << sfd << std::endl;

            currentSocket = sfd;

    }
```

My problem is that this code is connecting the socket, even if an IP address is not available. Check the results:

Here is the runtime output:

```
    Connecting to address 192.168.0.185 port 9090
    ADDRESS-------------> 0
    loop-----------------> 2
    sfd-----------------> 5
    sts-----------------> 0
    SOCKET-----------------> 5

$ ping 192.168.0.185
PING 192.168.0.185 (192.168.0.185) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 192.168.0.185 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.185 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 192.168.0.185 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
```

I would like to understand what´s going on here ? Why does it connects the socket to a port from a non-existant Ip Address ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are passing an IPv4 address, not a hostname, to `getaddrinfo()` (you should be specifying `AI_NUMERICHOST` in the `hints.ai_flags` field, though).  It is going to output a single `addrinfo` containing a `sockaddr_in` for that IP address as-is, it will not try to validate the IP's existence.  That is why `getaddrinfo()` is returning 0.

You are telling `getaddrinfo()` that you are going to be using a UDP (`SOCK_DGRAM`) socket, not a TCP (`SOCK_STREAM`) socket.  So the output `addrinfo` contains information for creating a UDP socket when calling `socket()`.

You are then calling `connect()` on a UDP socket.  In UDP, `connect()` does not actually create a physical connection, like it does for TCP.  It merely assigns the specified peer IP to the socket so that `send()` and `recv()` can then be used instead of `sendto()` and `recvfrom()`.  That is why `connect()` is returning 0 instead of failing.  Doing this allows `send()` to always send packets to the same IP, and `recv()` to only accept packets received from the same IP.

You are not actually sending any data yet, so the peer IP is not being validated at any step of your code.  Once you start sending data, the transmitted packets will end up receiving ICMP host unreachable errors from the network, thus causing `send()` and `recv()` to start failing.

So, if you want `connect()` to fail for a non-reachable IP address, create a TCP socket instead of a UDP socket.  Otherwise, if you continue using a UDP socket, you need to send data to the IP so the network will try to physically route it.

BTW, if `connect()` did fail, you would be leaking the output `addrinfo` as you are calling `freeaddrinfo()` only if `connect()` succeeds.  You need to call `freeaddrinfo()` anytime `getaddrinfo()` succeeds, regardless of how you use the `addrinfo` data.

Comment: Very well explained. Changed the socket to use TCP with `SOCKET_STREAM` parameter solved the issue. The `freeaddrinfo` leakage was also solved. Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 1):

A UDP 'connect' is not a network operation. It sets a condtion in the local API, that filters out datagrams from other hosts and allows you to use `send()` instead of `sendto()`. It won't fail, but subsequent sends will.